# Animate each div's height separately

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I need a way to animate a lot of divs without a class or id separately, let's say we have 10 divs and I want to animate each div's height with a set percentage.

I can do a random height to each of them like this:

```
function getRandomInt(min, max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min);
}

    $('div').each(function () {
        var height = getRandomInt(0, 200);
        console.log(height);
        $(this).animate({
            'height': height
        },400);

    });
```

But what if I want each div's height to correspond with the following ?

```
$(function () { 
    animateHeight('10%', '35%', '20%', '50%', '70%', '55%', '90%', '35%', '5%', '100%');
});
```

Here is a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/brilliancedisplay/av0o6f4j/4/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Push all the values in an array and use `each` index parameter to set the div height :

```js
var myArray = Array('60%', '35%', '20%', '50%', '70%', '55%', '90%', '35%', '5%', '100%');

function animateHeight(myArray) 
{
    $('div').each(function (index) {
        var height = myArray[index];
        console.log(height);
        $(this).animate({
            'height': height
        });
    });
}

animateHeight(myArray);
```

```css
ul li {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    width: 10px;
    margin: 10px 5px 0 0;
    height: 230px;
}
div {
    height:0;
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    background: #000;
    width: 5px;
    bottom: 0px;
    top:0;
    margin:auto;
    overflow:visible !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
    <li>
        <div></div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div></div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div></div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div></div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div></div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div></div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div></div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div></div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div></div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div></div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**UPDATE**

```
var myArray1 = Array('60%', '35%', '20%', '50%', '70%', '55%', '90%', '35%', '5%', '100%');

var myArray2 = Array('10%', '35%', '20%', '50%', '70%', '55%', '90%', '35%', '5%', '100%');

var myArrays = Array(myArray1, myArray2);

var inc = 0;

function animateHeight(myArray) {
    $('div').each(function (index) {
        var height = myArray[index];
        $(this).animate({
            'height': height
        });
    }).promise().done(function () {
        inc++;
        if (myArrays[inc] !== undefined) {
            animateHeight(myArrays[inc]);
        }
    });
}

animateHeight(myArrays[0]);
```

Comment: Thanks ^^ This will do, one more thing if I may, I presented the option with a function that contained the values cause I needed to animate them with more than one set of values. How would I go if I had 5 such Arrays and want to animate one after another?

Comment: @Alin I am sure that you can do something more elegant with JQuery Promise function, but here is a quick and dirty idea : https://jsfiddle.net/av0o6f4j/18/

Comment: Thanks, I didn't want to use any other scripts and would like to work on something to get it. I just got stuck...now I'm fine,thanks to you. Have a great day ;)

Comment: Awesome ^^ the first thing when I saw the set Interval in the last one was to make us of the .done() to run the other animation when the last one is completed ^^ Thansk

Comment: @Alin Final version : https://jsfiddle.net/ca2jch1r/2/ It is better because it doesn't use global variable. Best luck for your project